# animate 3 views one after the other

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, caanimation

i am trying to animate 3 different views one after the other to show syncing .how to achieve this using CAAnimation .
Tried doing it using Gcd by calling 3 methods one after the other where i was showing first circle and hiding other circles.But had faced some problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this without using animation.
Set tag to your three views for exa 1,2 and 3

```
 NSTimer *timerLabelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


 int counter = 0;
-(void)updateTimerLabel{



if (counter == 0) {

    UIView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:0];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *tempView1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *tempView2 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
if (counter == 1) {

    UIView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:0];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *tempView1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *tempView2 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}

if (counter == 2) {

    UIView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:0];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *tempView1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *tempView2 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //removed counter = 0; from here
}

//Update
counter ++;

if (counter == 3) {
    counter =0;
}


 }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: using NSTimer blocks UI. any other way ?

Comment: Check update part. this was a little mistake in counter increment. try like this, it's work fine in my demo. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `UIImageView.animationImages`, it's much easier and faster and less energy consuming than animations.